# Как узнать разницу между суммами столбцов в базе данных?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

Записать разность между сумм столбцов в другой столбец в sqlite.
В моем коде ошибка:

> misuse of aggregate function Sum()

```
curs.execute(f'INSERT INTO Финансы (Дата, Кредит, Комментарий) VALUES ("{data}","{summa}","{comm}")')
        q = f"Update Финансы set Баланс = Sum(Дебит) - Sum(Кредит)"
```

Название таблицы - Финансы.
Столбцы - Дата, Кредит(int), Дебит(int), Баланс(int), Комментарий.

Желаемый результат - После ввода значения в столбец Кредит, программа должна суммировать все значения данного столбца, также суммировать все значения столбца Дебит, после программа высчитывает разницу и передает данные в столбец Баланс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример sum(Дебит)=48000, sum(Кредит)=3000, Баланс=45000

Comment: Разве в update для set не нужно указать имя колонки для обновления?

Comment: И кста, столбец `Кредит`  существует ?

Comment: Все изменил, столбец существует, в него вводятся данные, после чего и происходит вычет

Comment: А что нельзя в вопросе показать название таблицы, название полей, минимальный пример данных, желаемый результат, в вопросе разность между столбцами, а в запросе разность сумм.

Comment: @jklll а столбец `Дебит` существует? :DDD    ..... ну смотри, ты пытаешься во все столбцы баланса вписать одно значение....Если у тебя 1000 записей, то во всех них будет записано, например, 999... наверное это не то, что нужно... Наверное ты хотел `Баланс = Дебит - Кредит` ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня Дебит и Кредит записывается из разных форм, поэтому они в разных строках, плюс в день может быть один Дебит и несколько кредитов. Столбец Дебит существует

Comment: Это учебная задача? Вопрос по тому, что алгоритм некорректный, например, ты хочешь записать свою запись, посчитал сумму и разность и в этот момент кто-то еще внес свою запись по этому же алгоритму, твоя запись не вошла в его сумму, потому что еще не записана, его сумма не войдет в твою запись и вся таблица поплывет, причем все последующие записи. Это норм?

Comment: Учебная задача. Один пользователь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея такая

```
data, summa, comm = 0,0,0 # Это условно

credit=int(input('Введите кредит'))
bal=conn.execute('SELECT SUM(Дебет)-SUM(Кредит) FROM Финансы').fetchone()

ibal=bal[0]+credit #Я не знаю здесь складывать или вычитать

conn.execute('INSER INTO Финансы (Дата, Кредит, Баланс, Комментарий) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', (data, summa, ibal, comm))
```

Я "Дебет" написал, а не "Дебит" 
 `Дата, Кредит, Баланс, Комментарий` в поле "Кредит" что нужно вносить в базу?

Comment: Я переделала чуть под себя, все замечательно, спасибо большое